# PostgreSQL psql -c SQL statement Where clause Single Quote Issue

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, psql

Table data:
sno name trans_date
1 Jon 2023-01-01
2 Sam 2023-01-02

I am trying to run a Postgresql SQL statement via psql -c.
Statement looks like this

psql -c 'Select 1 from test_tab where trans_date = ''2023-01-01'' '

also same results for this statement:
psql -c 'select 1 from test_tab where name = ''Jon'' '

I get results of same statememt when running in Dbeaver but in Shell terminal I get
(0 rows).  It seems like the issue is with single quote and I can't find any solution online.  If I compare numbers it works, only issues is with characters and dates.

Comment: Try reversing the quotes, e.g. use double quotes first and the single quotes for the value of the `where` statement.

Comment: Presumably executing a single constant query is not your real task.  There are a bunch of ways to fix this problem, and which one works best depends on what your real task is.

Comment: ...mind, _in general_, shell languages are not well-suited to running arbitrary SQL queries with untrusted values. Once upon a time, about 20 years ago, I wrote a command-line SQL client with proper bind variable support that wrote NUL-delimited output, accepted key/value pairs as separate argv values on input, &c; but it was property of a former employer that never released it (and is now long since out of business).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, so after 20 years and being out of business (legally) they still own that software you wrote?

Comment: @Jetchisel, I didn't retain my own copy, which is a damned shame -- I actually did get a signed letter granting the ability to relicense a bunch of things I wrote there under a trio of OSS licenses, but I'd have to actually have a copy of the code to make any use of it.

Comment: @Jetchisel, (incidentally, that former employer is where https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/isg-state-machine-framework came from; one of the few tools developed there, and subject to that grant of permission, I was able to get my hands on after leaving)

Comment: @Jetchisel, ...but yes -- I'm in the US; there's no automatic transfer of copyright even when current ownership is unknown or nonexistent. Probably copyright is technically held by a bank the company owed money to or some other creditor; it would cost lawyer-fee money to even do the research.

Comment: Well that is a  Lesson learned, I hope. would have been nice to use/see it out there.